# How to use the Blazemeter Step-by-step debugger?

Tags: jmeter, performance, jmeter-plugins, debugging, blazemeter

I have added the Step-by-step debugger via the JMeter plugins manager but I don't have any idea how to start using it. Any suggestions on how I can start using it for debugging purposes?

Comment: Not sure why this is too broad? Seems there is only a single way to use the debugger in blazemeter tests, not?

Answer (score 2):

You can move to debugging your script in following way:

**Step 1 :** Create the script as per your business requirement. Here i have created one sample test plan for the reference where i have setup all required things as mentioned in snap :

[image]

**Step 2:** If debug plugin has successfully installed then it will appear in the strip right below the menu bar, click on it

[image]

It will open new debug window where you will see the debug options as shown in the below snap :

[image]

**Step 3** : Now select the Test Plan and click on the **Start** button, It will start debugging your script

[image]

Test plan component will display highlighted which is currently being executing , to move the next step click on **Step Over** Button, Here you can analyze your script the flow and variables, logs and so many things as options are there.

**EDIT:**

**Note: Jmeter 3.0 and 3.1 supports `blazemeter step by step debugger` plugin version 3.0. `blazemeter step by step debugger` plugin version 4.0 supported by Jmeter 3.2**

Comment: Thanks! In my case nothing happens on clicking the Blazemeter debug icon, the one you mentioned in step 2.

Comment: @Rohan Kalia, I'm using jmeter 3.1 and  `BlazeMeter Step-by-step Debugger ` `0.3` it wont work with plugin version `0.4` so make sure you have installed correct version, If accediently you have installed wron version then go to `plugin manager` --> `uncheck debugger plugin` present in installed plugin tab--> click `apply change and restart jmeter` button and again install the correct version (select the version from the dropdown comes while click the desired plugin)

Comment: @RohanKalia, If answer is helpful for you then don't forget to `accept` it

Answer (score 2):

Given successful installation you should be able to see `Step-by-Step Debugger` entry under "Run" section of JMeter's main menu:

[image: JMeter Step By Step Debugger]

On start you will see debugger window where you will be able to inspect JMeter Variables, JMeter Properties, evaluate expressions and see JMeter log file

[image: JMeter Step By Step debugger]

- Make sure you have latest JMeter version, you can always grab one on [JMeter Downloads page](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi)
- Make sure you have latest Step-by-Step Debugger plugin version, [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/) can be used for installing plugins and keeping them up-to-date

Refer to [A Step-by-Step Debugger for JMeter - It’s Not a Dream Anymore](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/step-step-debugger-jmeter-it%E2%80%99s-not-dream-anymore) for comprehensive usage instructions.